# Swift Generics Dictionary or Array of Dictionaries

Tags: generics, swift4

I'm trying to set up a generic method in swift where the parameter can be either a dictionary of `[String:Any]?` or an array of dictionaries `[[String:Any]]?`, both optional. I'm not familiar with the generics syntax to this level in Swift, but I tried this:

```
private class func weirdGenerics<T>(thing:T) where T:Optional<[(String, Any)]>, T:Optional<[[(String, Any)]]>{

    }
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Type 'T' Constrained to non-protocol, non-class type
```

For both of those generic restrictions. How would you accomplish the syntax I'm searching for here?

Comment: What you want to achieve with this? Any insight will be helpful. The method could/should only accepts array of dictionaries. It can contain a single dictionary also. So you can loop through.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan I want a method that will accept either an optional dictionary or an optional array of dictionaries. The current code does not work, as I get the given error at compile time. I'm assuming it is a syntax issue and not that this isn't possible in the Swift language. While I understand I could just accept an array and loop, that is not the solution I'm looking for. I want to know the syntax as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

The Swift compiler complains because Generic constraints(for example: ... where T: Equatable) can be either class or a protocol type, whereas you specify an enum (Optional) as a constraint. To solve this you could do the following:

```
private class func weirdGenerics(thing: Optional<[(String, Any)]>) {

}
private class func weirdGenerics(thing: Optional<[[(String, Any)]]>) {

}
```